# Display the foreground image at center

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a rails3 application which has user profiles. Each profile may have 4 profile images of different sizes with a slideshow. I have one background image xx.gif.

If profile image has size less than 640*480, then xx.gif should be visible at the background and the smaller profile image in the foreground. Smaller profile image should also be at the center corresponding to background image.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

*HTML*

```
<div id="main">
  <img id="image1" alt="test" src="/images/image.png" class="center">
</div>​
```

*CSS*

```
#main {
    background: url("/images/bg.jpg") 50% 50% no-repeat; 
    border:1px solid #eee; 
    width:500px; 
    height:400px;
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[**`Fiddle here`**](http://jsfiddle.net/jXUTc/)